# Delete all posts of a custom post type—efficiently

Tags: custom-post-types, database, performance

I'm looking for a safe and fast way to delete all of one custom post type's posts. Using `get_posts()` and `wp_delete_post()` for each returned post does not work; it's not fast enough due to the sheer amount of database queries involved (timeout error).

Preferably, I'm looking for a single database query to run that deletes all posts that are of a custom post type. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this a one-time event?  If so, quick sql query via phpMyAdmin seems easiest.  If this is a house-keeping step needed to be done programmatically/repeatedly, that won't help you.

Comment: It needs to be done regularly, without manual database access, unfortunately.

Comment: Roger that.  I would recommend looking at `wpdb` class then.  Preferred method and "the WP way" for working directly with the DB.  Let us know if you need help with that query.   I can post a full answer later if needed https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: How many posts are you needing to delete? And how often? A raw SQL query might be quick but unless you are very, very careful you will be leaving orphan data all through the database. And WordPress keeps data in a lot of tables with some complicated cross-linking.

Comment: Use `'fields' => 'ids',` in `get_posts` to get only post ID. This is all you need and it will significantely speed up your query

Comment: @s_ha_dum Orphan data is what I'm trying to prevent, obviously. I'm deleting around 5.5K posts (and adding around 5.5K posts, so if you've got a solution for that, I'm all ears). It's a syncing operation that happens at arbitrary intervals. Could happen once a week or once a month.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Good point, I'll try that and see where it gets me. But I suspect a single query will be much more efficient.

Comment: @jdm2112 I probably won't get around to this until Monday, but this looks like the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcusMcLean : obviously, you missed my point ;) A single post has data in the posts table, the postmeta table, the taxonomy table(s), and possibly the options table. Any pure SQL query you write to delete those posts will be quite complicated. You stand a good chance of leaving things behind in those various tables. I would try deleting, say, 50 at a time at 5 minute intervals using the Core functions and `wp_cron()`

Answer (score 40):

You can delete all post via `$wpdb`

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='post_type';
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM wp_posts);
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM wp_posts)
```

or use this query replace it with {{your CPT}} with your Custom Post  Type

```
DELETE a,b,c
    FROM wp_posts a
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b
        ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c
        ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
    WHERE a.post_type = '{{your CPT}}';
```

Comment: this would probably work fine, but don't forget about term counts in one of the term tables. WordPress should have a function to update this.

Comment: users also have post counts on users screen, not sure if this data is saved beforehand or calculated on page load.

Comment: @JoelM The count column exists in the database table `wp_term_taxonomy`. It seems like the function you are looking for to update the count is `wp_update_term_count($terms, $taxonomy, false)` or `wp_update_term_count_now($terms, $taxonomy)` defined in `wp-includes/taxonomy.php`.

Answer (score 16):

This can now be done with the [WordPress CLI](https://wp-cli.org) using **[wp post delete](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/delete/)**. Once the CLI is installed, the following terminal command (while in your site's root directory) will delete all posts of type `mycustomtype`:

`wp post delete $(wp post list --post_type='mycustomtype' --format=ids)`

No raw SQL (**shudder**), no worrying about timeouts, and it's fast. For example, I just deleted ~2500 posts in less than two minutes.

Comment: This worked for me to delete ~12k posts. Handled it no problem. Use the `--force` flag if you want to skip the "trash can" and permanently delete.

Answer (score 12):

You can delete all posts of a custom post type in various methods but here I am gonna show you how to do this without using SQL query.
Here, for example, our post type is **product**

```
$allposts= get_posts( array('post_type'=>'product','numberposts'=>-1) );
foreach ($allposts as $eachpost) {
wp_delete_post( $eachpost->ID, true );
}
```

[See full tutorial Reference Here](https://www.codespeedy.com/delete-all-posts-from-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Read the OP again: "Using `get_posts()` and `wp_delete_post()` for each returned post does not work; it's not fast enough due to the sheer amount of database queries involved (timeout error)."

You are using the two functions he doesn't want to use.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But just to play safe and also delete with terms, comments and meta with count on terms.  It's the perfect method. maybe we can use cron for it

Comment: If you pass `'fields' => 'ids'` to `get_posts`, then it will return an array of IDs instead of an an array of post objects, which should hopefully speed this up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have prefixed your CPT post type and your CPT taxonomies with eg. 'abc_my_custom_post_type' and 'abc_my_taxonomy' then it's trivial to remove everything from db with two queries:

```
DELETE a,b
FROM      $wpdb->posts    a
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta b ON a.ID = b.post_id
WHERE a.post_type LIKE 'abc_%';
            
DELETE a,b,c
FROM      $wpdb->term_taxonomy      a
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships b ON a.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms              c ON a.term_id = c.term_id
WHERE a.taxonomy LIKE 'abc_%'
```